# Does polarity of differential DisplayPort signals matter

Tags: differential, routing, displayport

I am routing a DisplayPort interface. I know from PCIe that the polarity of the differential pairs does not matter. So if it is helpful during routing I can connect the n to the p pin and vice-versa.

Is the same true for DisplayPort signals? Can I swap the negative and positive signals if convenient?

Comment: What is the part number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Polarity matters, there is no automatic sense. You cannot swap lanes and lane polarities. However, depending on what chip you are using, the chip may have configurable lane polarity inversion or swapping between lanes.